# Java compile time error non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

i am having trouble compiling this code about Graph theory in hackerrank, it seems to work elsewhere i dont know how to fix it. I need to find if all the vertices of the graph are connected or not. If they are i want to print 1 if not 0. I am stuck at this error and i cant seem to find how to work it out. I would be very glad if anyone can help me out with this.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Solution {

class CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph {
        class Graph{
        int vertices;
        LinkedList<Integer> adjList [];

        public Graph(int vertices){
            this.vertices = vertices;
            adjList = new LinkedList[vertices];
            for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
                adjList[i] = new LinkedList<>();
            }
        }

        public void addEdge(int source, int destination){
            adjList[source].addFirst(destination);
            adjList[destination].addFirst(source);
        }
    }

    public void isConnected(Graph graph){

        int vertices = graph.vertices;
        LinkedList<Integer> adjList [] = graph.adjList;

        boolean[] visited = new boolean[vertices];

        DFS(0, adjList, visited);

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <visited.length ; i++) {
            if(visited[i])
                count++;
        }
        if(vertices==count){
            System.out.println(1);
        }else{
            System.out.println(0);
        }
    }

    public void DFS(int source, LinkedList<Integer> adjList [], boolean[] visited){

        visited[source] = true;

        for (int i = 0; i <adjList[source].size() ; i++) {
            int neighbor = adjList[source].get(i);
            if(visited[neighbor]==false){
                DFS(neighbor, adjList, visited);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph graph = new Graph(6);
        graph.addEdge(5,4);
        graph.addEdge(1,2);
        graph.addEdge(1,3);
        graph.addEdge(2,4);
        graph.addEdge(3,4);

        CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph c = new CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph();
        c.isConnected(graph);
    }

}
}
```

Error Output:

```
Solution.java:62: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context Graph graph = new Graph(6); Solution.java:69: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph c = new CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph(); ^ Solution.java:61: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class Solution.CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph public static void main(String[] args) { modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
```

Comment: Solution.java:62: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        Graph graph = new Graph(6);
            
Solution.java:69: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph c = new CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph();
                                             ^
Solution.java:61: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class Solution.CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Comment: Forgot to add the Errors sorry

Answer (score 0):

Make the inner class `Graph` and `CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph` static : `static class Graph` and `static class CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph`

Then, instiantiate your Graph by `new Solution.CheckUndirectedDisconnectedGraph.Graph(6)`

You should also move your main method under the `Solution` class

Comment: then i get this error... Solution.java:10: error: modifier static not allowed here
        static class Graph{
               ^
Note: Solution.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

Comment: Just edited my post, I've misread the class structure.

Comment: You should also avoid using nested classes, unless you have a good reason to use them.